# Can anyone explain this TypeScript snippet?

Tags: typescript

Interfaces are used as blueprints for a contract.
And yet in TypeScript you have this odd syntax (essentially having a new() inside an 
interface). Is this some sort of factory?

```
interface IControllerDetails {
     controller : { new(...args:string[]): void ;};
}
```

tx for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the `controller` property of objects that conform to the interface have a constructor and the constructor can take any number of string parameters.

So you can write code like the following:

```
let controllerDetails: IControllerDetails = ...;

let controller = new controllerDetails.controller("any", "amount", "of string args");
```

The weird part is that when creating new instances of the controller property it returns `void`. So in the code shown, `controller` is of type `void`. I'm not sure why someone would want to do that unless just calling `new controllerDetails.controller()` did all that was necessary, but even still that's strange.

An example of a value that conforms to the interface would be something like this:

```
class Controller {
    constructor(...args: string[]) {
    }
}

let controllerDetails: IControllerDetails = {
    // you could inline a class here if you wanted by using a class expression
    controller: Controller
};
```

Edit: By "inline", I just meant you could write this if you wanted, which isn't commonly done:

```
let controllerDetails: IControllerDetails = {
    controller: class Controller {
        constructor(...args: string[]) {
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, what drove it home for me was the statement that "It means that the controller property of objects that conform to the interface have a constructor and the constructor can take any number of string parameters."  TX again...

Comment: Can you please also show what you mean by "you could inline a class here if you wanted by using a class expression"

Comment: ```let controllerDetails: ISample = {
                controller: function(){
                    return class MyClass {
                        constructor(...args:string[]) {
                        }
                    }
                }()
            };```

Comment: @user2040670 no, that would be a function that returns a class `controller: () => { new(...args: string[]): void; }`. I updated the answer with an example. Saying that about using a class expression was just a sidenote... it's not common syntax.

Answer (score 3):

To break this down:

```
interface IControllerDetails {
     controller : { new(...args:string[]): void ;};
}
```

Let's start here

```
interface IControllerDetails {
```

This declares a type called `IControllerDetails`

```
     controller : { new(...args:string[]): void ;};
     ~~~~~~~~~~
```

It has a property called `controller`

```
     controller : { new(...args:string[]): void ;};
                  ~                              ~
```

The type of the `controller` property is an object type with some members. There could have been more properties declared between the `{}`s, but there's only one here

```
     controller : { new(...args:string[]): void ;};
                    ~~~
```

The only member of the `controller` property is a *construct signature*. This means you can invoke the `new` operator on the `controller` property.

```
     controller : { new(...args:string[]): void ;};
                        ~~~           ~~
```

This constructor takes between zero and infinity arguments.

```
     controller : { new(...args:string[]): void ;};
                           ~~~~
```

The name of the parameter list is `args`, though this doesn't affect anything.

```
     controller : { new(...args:string[]): void ;};
                                ~~~~~~
```

All of the arguments have to be of type `string`

```
     controller : { new(...args:string[]): void ;};
                                           ~~~~
```

The constructor doesn't have to return anything. In practice, what they're saying here is that you can return an object of any kind (because it's safe to assign a function returning *more* to a function returning *less*).

Comment: Thank you, what drove it home for me was the statement that "It means that the controller property of objects that conform to the interface have a constructor and the constructor can take any number of string parameters."  TX again...

Answer (score 0):

basically, that syntax of `someMember : { new(...args:string[]): IAnotherSample ;};` means the Class must have the same constructor signature that matches the interface contract. For anyone that needs the complete source here you go:

```

```
interface ISample {
    // someMember requires a class with a constructor that has matching signature and return type
    someMember : { new(...args:string[]): IAnotherSample ;};
}
interface IAnotherSample {
    someNum: number;
}
class MyClass implements IAnotherSample{
    public someNum:number;
    constructor(...args:string[]) {
    }
}

let sample: ISample = {
    someMember: MyClass
};

let sampleInstance = new sample.someMember('123');
```

```